# Help with Web forms

Tags: 7, webforms

I would like to create a simple form that allows a teacher to enter the individual names of their pupils.
I would then like to create another form that returns the individual names of the pupils one at a time and allows the teacher to input a score next to the name.
is there a module that would allow me to do this

Comment: OK maybe I was a bit hasty closing this...it would be better if you could add a lot more detail to your question though, no-one's going to do _all_ of the work for you - you need to give us something to go on, let us know that you've actually tried to solve the problem yourself, and how, etc

Answer (score 2):

drupal itself provide a module "webform" for manipulating webform

before you use module just go through readme.txt for better understanding
just download the module :)

Answer (score 0):

alternatively [Entity Form](http://drupal.org/project/entityform)

I find this one more powerful out of box, however it all depends on what exactly you would like to achieve.